# Handling a System Restart/Crash in between changing a Flag

Tags: algorithm, deadlock, flags

I have a following scenario

> 1. Change a Flag = start (in database)
> 2. Do some processing
> 3. Update the Flag back to Finished (in database)

Suppose the system crashes during the step 2. Ideally I would want to set the Flag back to Finished. But because of the system crash it doesn't and it falls into deadlock for that task.

What are the standard solutions/approaches/algorithms followed to address such scenario?

**Edit: How the deadlock occurs?**
The task will be picked only if the Flag = Finished. Flag = start means it is in progress in the middle of something. So when there is a crash, the task is not complete but the Flag is also not set to Finish next the the system runs. So the task is not going to be picked again.

Comment: you haven't explained how and why "it falls into deadlock". also more details what the flag is used for can be helpful too.

Comment: The task will be picked only if the Flag = Finished. Flag = start means it is in progress in the middle of something. So when there is a crash, the task is not complete but the Flag is also not set to Finish next the the system runs. So the task is not going to be picked again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any simple solution here.

If your tasks execution time is predictable enough you can store a timestamp of task execution start in your DB and return task to "empty" state (not started yet) on timeout.

Or you can store process ID in your DB and implement a supervisor process that will launch your "executor" processes and check their exit code. If process crashed supervisor would "reinitialise" all tasks marked with crashed process ID.